# restore mongodb sharded cluster to another server

Tags: backup, mongodb, restore

MongoDB version is 2.4.12
Production Server has 3 shards and each shard have another 2 replica sets.
Config server & router also runs on these servers.

Backup procedure :
1. Shutdown one of replica set on each shard.
2. We use mongodump to backup config server.
3. Cold backup od /data & /log folders.

Restore Procedure :
Restore will happen on only 3 servers so there will not be any replica sets.
Server name where it is getting restored, is different than where backup happend so server name is going to change.

Can someone put high level steps how do I restore ?
** Restore Config server from dump ( Is this 1st step)
** Copy all /data and logs to these three servers.
** Is there anything I need to change in config server or any other settings since Production server did have replica set configuration but this new server will not have replica set.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Restore Config Server using mongorestore.
2. Restore data backup for each shards.
3. Change Config settings. use config and see db.shards.find(), you will see setting as related to production server, which you need to update it based on new server settings.